# 1996 Mongoose size 19" Crossway 650 replacement size inner tube

Tags: innertube

My bicycle has a label saying  size 19"  . What is the tire size for my bicycle  and the what is the  inner tube size?

Comment: I'm guessing the 19" value is printed on the frame somewhere, not on the tire or wheel.  Look VERY CAREFULLY on the side of the tire for measurements -- You will see something like 24x1-3/4 or 24x1.75, and usually just before that a cryptic number like 45-507.  Find the numbers, write them down, then report back,  (Or refer to [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html), the god of bicycle technical info.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bicycle Blue Book](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=59542), this thing shipped with 700c wheels and 700x38 tires.

So, you need 700x38 tires (or something similar, e.g. 700x35) and a tube which is rated for 700x38 tires (these are sold by ranges, e.g. 700x38-45 tubes).